# Why is the .toSorted() method not available on HackerRank?

Tags: javascript

I needed to solve a coding exercise without mutating the original array (parameter).
Coding Problem:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.
>
> **Example**
>
> The minimum sum is  and the maximum sum is . The function prints
>
> ```
> 16 24
> ```
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the miniMaxSum function in the editor below.
>
> miniMaxSum has the following parameter(s):
>
> - arr: an array of  integers
>
> Print
>
> Print two space-separated integers on one line: the minimum sum and the maximum sum of  of  elements.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> A single line of five space-separated integers.*
>
> **Constraints**
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print two space-separated long integers denoting the respective minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. (The output can be greater than a 32 bit integer.)

This was my function:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let minSum = 0;
    let maxSum = 0;
    let maxArray = arr.toSorted((a, b) => (b -a));
    let minArray = arr.toSorted((a, b) => (a - b));
  
    // Write your code here
    console.log(maxArray, minArray)
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 ; i++){
        minSum += minArray[i];
        maxSum += maxArray[i];
    }
    console.log(minSum, maxSum)
}
```

I got this error when I tried to run the code:

[image: Error message]

I used this instead:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let minSum = 0;
    let maxSum = 0;
    let maxArray = [...arr].sort((a, b) => (b - a));
    let minArray = [...arr].sort((a, b) => (a - b));
    // Write your code here

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 ; i++){
        minSum += minArray[i];
        maxSum += maxArray[i];
    }
    console.log(minSum, maxSum)
}
```

[image: Success Message]

Why didn't `toSorted()` work?

Comment: `toSorted` method is quite new, it looks like the engine running the code doesn't know the method yet.

Comment: It [appears](https://candidatesupport.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402913877523-Execution-Environment-and-Samples) HackerRank uses NodeJS v18.15.0 for it's JS runtime, which doesn't support `.toSorted()`.

Comment: btw, you need only a single sorting. take first and last item as min and max, if ascending.

Answer (score 5):

Because as of this writing on 2024-03-04, [Hackerrank uses Node.js v18.15.0](https://candidatesupport.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402913877523-Execution-Environment-and-Samples) *(link from [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons))*, which doesn't have `toSorted`. (Node.js [v20.0.0+ does have it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V20.md#2023-04-18-version-2000-current-rafaelgss).) The [change array by copy](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy) proposal that adds `toSorted` and various other methods to arrays is quite recent: ES2023. So while recent versions of major engines (V8 [the one that Node.js uses], JavaScriptCore, SpiderMonkey) will have it available unflagged, only slightly out-of-date versions won't have it (or will have it only behind a flag). Presumably at some point Hackerrank will update to a version that has it

Comment: Do I understand the toSorted correctly as a shortcut to arr.slice(0).sort() or is there something more to it?

Comment: @mplungjan - Conceptually, yeah, although that isn't quite the way it's [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tosorted). The spec has the sort operation create a temporary list, and then creates an array from that list. So if you had an array subclass through which you were observing mutations, you'd only see mutations populating it with the result, not all the mutations of a sort. At least, that's how I read the spec, I haven't deep-dived on this proposal.